# sublimegdb can not stop in the breakpoint

Tags: sublimetext

I hava install sublimeGDB in my sublime text 2, and my setting is right.
Then I press F9 in a line to set a breakpoint. When I press F5 to run, I found my program can not stop on the breakpoint, and the program finished running.
The information show below is "GDB session ended". The GDB view is appear in just 0.5 sec., and then disappear.

Comment: anyone to answer my question?

Comment: Having the same problem.  GDB works fine & allows me to set breakpoints at the command line (used with golang).

Comment: I've also been having the same issue. Ubuntu 12.04 with SublimeText Build 3065

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile your executable with debug information included by adding `-g` option to the GDB command line which is not being added by default by Sublime Text C++ build system. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23790095/853791) answer for more details how to do it.