# How to edit Sublime Text build settings?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to enable `-std=gnu++11` in Sublime Text 3's C++ Single File build on Ubuntu 12.04.

I have already upgraded the tool chain to the latest g++ and do not want to see the following error on every build:

> error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

I browsed to `/home/myuname/.config/sublime-text-3` but cannot find any file to edit.

How can I edit the build settings?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

***edited***

My [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23790095/4) works, but there's a much better way of doing this, by creating your own [build system](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html). This use case is exactly why the feature is there.

Go to **`Tools`** → **`Build System`** → **`New Build System…`** (all the way at the bottom) and enter the contents below. Save as `C++ 11 Single File.sublime-build`, and it will now be accessible in the build system menu. Select it, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to build, and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to run the resulting program. Or you can use a `Build and Run` option and call it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, then selecting that option.

```json
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-std=gnu++11", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["${file_path}/${file_base_name}"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Build and Run",
            "cmd": ["g++ -std=gnu++11 ${file} -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name} && ${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

If you need to edit it in the future, the file is in the `User` folder of `Packages`. The `Packages` directory is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` or `~/.config/sublime-text/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` or `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages`

<sup>The exact path depends on version and whether or not you upgraded from Sublime Text 3.</sup>

Comment: I Am doing that.

Why has it not been stated on the sublime website is what I wonder.

Comment: Does not build , the same error I get when I do ctrl+b


{
 "shell_cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\"",
 "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",
 "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

 "variants":
 [
  {
   "name": "Run",
   "shell_cmd": "g++ -std=gnu++11 \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""
  }
 ]
}

Comment: I want to do a "-lpthread" for each file , To enable multi threading , 

"cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", 
"-std=gnu++11","-lpthread" ,"-g"],




Does not ----link 

+++links 


the pthread library to my cpp file.



thanks

Comment: @raikrahul - as far as I know, the options should come before the file name - `["g++", "-std=gnu++11", "-lpthread", "-g", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"]`. Basically, write out the command the same way you'd run it at the command line, or in your Makefile. And speaking of which, instead of editing the `.sublime-build` file for more and more complex options, I'd highly recommend using a Makefile instead, and just have the build system run `make`.

Comment: Thank you for referecne to PackageReourceViewer. It helps a lot!

Comment: If you add/create a custom build script, it will be in a different location. For example, mine is in: **~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/c++11.sublime-build**

Comment: If it is a custom build, on MacOS they are on: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User`

Comment: Why do they make it so hard to edit or even rename these files?! Why not have an edit option in the Sublime menu. This is crazy.

Comment: Can confirm this works on MacOS Big Sur 11.5

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem is that in Windows, ST3 was calling py instead of python which was the default. If you change python in "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"] for your local python interpreter, the new system should work.

```html
{
        "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
        "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
        "selector": "source.python",
    
        "env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
    
        "windows": {
            "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
        },
    
        "variants":
        [
            {
                "name": "Syntax Check",
                "cmd": ["python3", "-m", "py_compile", "$file"],
    
                "windows": {
                    "cmd": ["py", "-m", "py_compile", "$file"],
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```