# Change Sublime 3's Python Build to use py instead of python as the command

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I am using Python 3.4 and Sublime Text 3 in a Windows 7 machine.

If I go to the cmd prompt and type

```
python
```

I get

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command...
```

If I type

```
py
```

It works and I get

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

When I use the Sublime 3 build command it issues the command

```
python -u "C:\Whatever\MyPythonFile.py"
```

Which does not work.  Apparently I need Sublime Text 3 to use the command 'py' instead of 'python' when building.

**What are the exact steps I need to take to change Sublime Text 3 to get it to run python scripts in my environment using the build command?**

I have been searching for quite a while and all I can find are instructions on how to add the python directory to PATH, which does not seem to be my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Sublime Text 3, packages are zipped up in `.sublime-package` archives, making them invisible to you. Luckily, there is a package you can download to work around this:

1. Download [Package Resource Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789410/how-to-edit-sublime-text3-build-settings) using [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).
2. `ctrl` + `shift` + `P`, type `PRV` and click `Extract Package`. Extract the `Python` package.
3. `Preferences` -> `Browse Packages`. Your `Python` folder should be here now. Open it, find `Python.sublime-build`.
4. Now, I'm not 100% positive on this part, because I've never heard of this problem you're having, but you should be able to change your `.sublime-build` file as follows:

   ```
   {
       "cmd": ["py", "-u", "$file"],
       "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
       "selector": "source.python"
   }
   ```

This should run it with `py -u "C:\Whatever\yourFile.py"` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: So far so good, but how do I "change [my] .sublime-build file"?

Comment: Actually this one gives the instructions on how to change the sublime-build setting http://stackoverflow.com/a/23790095/2779792

Comment: By the way, this did solve my python build problem which is very strange because search results seem like I'm the first person in the history of the Internet to have this issue.  All I did was install Python, install Sublime Text 3, and boom, it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry I've been away for a bit, I'm assuming you figured it out but essentially you just open up the `.sublime-build` file as a text file or with sublime or whatever you feel like doing and change the `"cmd"` line to `["py", "-u", "$file"],`, for anyone interested.