# How to run SublimeText with visual studio environment enabled

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2015, environment-variables, sublimetext3

**OVERVIEW**

Right now I got these 2 programs on my windows taskbar:

- SublimeText3 target:

  ```
  "D:\software\SublimeText 3_x64\sublime_text.exe"
  ```
- VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt target:

  ```
  %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64
  ```

Goal here is running Sublime Text with vs2015 environment enabled.

1. One option would be open the vs command prompt and then run sublime text from there, `> sublime_text`  (this is not good one, I want it to be a **non-interactive process**)
2. Another option would be modifying somehow the sublimetext symlink target from the taskbar so I could open sublime with vs2015 environment enabled just clicking the icon

**QUESTION**

How could I acomplish option 2?

NS: I want to get Sublime Text 3 to run vcvarsall.bat properly only **once** at startup (not at build time on any build system)

**ATTEMPTS**

My first attempt was trying to understand how bat files executed so I tested
some basic batch files:

- bat1.bat: It opens sublime text succesfully

  ```
  sublime_text
  ```
- bat2.bat: It opens vs command prompt succesfully and it waits for user to type commands

  ```
  cmd /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64
  ```
- bat3.bat: Open vs command prompt but it won't open ST, unless you type exit once the command prompt is shown

  ```
  %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64
  sublime_text
  ```
- bat4.bat: Open vs command prompt but it doesn't open ST, same case than bat3.bat

  ```
  %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64 && sublime_text
  ```
- bat5.bat: Open vs command prompt but it doesn't open ST, same case than bat{4,3}.bat

  ```
  %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64 & sublime_text
  ```

After these attempts I've decided to read some docs trying to find some hints about [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) but it didn't make any difference.

Another idea was using conemu customized tasks, something like:

```
{vs2015}: cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 & sublime_text
```

and then having a bat file calling conemu like this:

```
D:\software\ConEmuPack.151205\ConEmu64.exe /single -cmd {vs2015}
```

the result was +/- what I wanted, but 2 terminals and a new sublime session would be spawned. What I'm looking for is just opening a SublimeText session with the right environment, so I consider this not a good solution, plus, it requires to have conemu installed.

After all those attempts I thought maybe using python to open a command prompt and typing&running "magically" some commands could be helpful but I don't know how to do it.

Conclusion: Till the date the problem remains unsolved...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aside of the ways that have already been mentioned in the question and the previous answer, another way to go is something akin to what @LinuxDisciple mentioned in their answer; have Sublime internally fire up the batch file once at Sublime start up to do what you need to do.

An example of this in action is the following plugin. To start with, add the following settings to your user preferences (`Preferences > Settings` or `Preferences > Settings - User`). Here I'm using the setup for my own local machine; update the path to suit for your version of Visual Studio:

```
"vc_vars_cmd": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat",
"vc_vars_arch": "amd64",
```

The `vc_vars_cmd` setting is required by the following plugin, but the `vc_vars_arch` setting is optional; if it is not given, it defaults to `amd64`.

Next, select `Tools > Developer > New Plugin` from the menu and replace the stub plugin code with the following and save it in the default location that Sublime defaults to as something like `set_vc_vars.py`:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

from threading import Thread
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from os import environ

SENTINEL="SUBL_VC_VARS"

def _get_vc_env():
    """
    Run the batch file specified in the vc_vars_cmd setting (with an
    optional architecture type) and return back a dictionary of the
    environment that the batch file sets up.

    Returns None if the preference is missing or the batch file fails.
    """
    settings = sublime.load_settings("Preferences.sublime-settings")
    vars_cmd = settings.get("vc_vars_cmd")
    vars_arch = settings.get("vc_vars_arch", "amd64")

    if vars_cmd is None:
        print("set_vc_vars: Cannot set Visual Studio Environment")
        print("set_vc_vars: Add 'vc_vars_cmd' setting to settings and restart")
        return None

    try:
        # Run the batch, outputting a sentinel value so we can separate out
        # any error messages the batch might generate.
        shell_cmd = "\"{0}\" {1} && echo {2} && set".format(
            vars_cmd, vars_arch, SENTINEL)

        output = Popen(shell_cmd, stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()

        lines = [line.strip() for line in output.decode("utf-8").splitlines()]
        env_lines = lines[lines.index(SENTINEL) + 1:]
    except:
        return None

    # Convert from var=value to dictionary key/value pairs. We upper case the
    # keys, since Python does that to the mapping it stores in environ.
    env = {}
    for env_var in env_lines:
        parts = env_var.split("=", maxsplit=1)
        env[parts[0].upper()] = parts[1]

    return env

def install_vc_env():
    """
    Try to collect the appropriate Visual Studio environment variables and
    set them into the current environment.
    """
    vc_env = _get_vc_env()
    if vc_env is None:
        print("set_vc_vars: Unable to fetch the Visual Studio Environment")
        return sublime.status_message("Error fetching VS Environment")

    # Add newly set environment variables
    for key in vc_env.keys():
        if key not in environ:
            environ[key] = vc_env[key]

    # Update existing variables whose values changed.
    for key in environ:
        if key in vc_env and environ[key] != vc_env[key]:
            environ[key] = vc_env[key]

    # Set a sentinel variable so we know not to try setting up the path again.
    environ[SENTINEL] = "BOOTSTRAPPED"
    sublime.status_message("VS Environment enabled")

def plugin_loaded():
    if sublime.platform() != "windows":
        return sublime.status_message("VS is not supported on this platform")

    # To reload the environment if it changes, restart Sublime.
    if SENTINEL in environ:
        return sublime.status_message("VS Environment already enabled")

    # Update in the background so we don't block the UI
    Thread(target=install_vc_env).start()
```

Once you save the plugin, Sublime will load it and execute the `plugin_loaded` function, which will do all of the work.You should see the status bar say `VS Environment Enabled` if it worked.

If you see `Error Fetching VS Environment` double check that the path to the batch file is correct (note that you need to double all path separators to make them JSON compliant).

This operates very similarly to (and is vaguely based on) the [Fix Mac Path](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Fix%20Mac%20Path) package, which does something similar to update the path in Sublime on MacOS, where the vagaries of the OS cause GUI applications to have their environment set in a way different than terminal applications.

The general idea is that the batch file is executed in a sub-process, and then before returning we also execute the `set` command to get the command interpreter to dump its entire environment to the console, which the plugin captures.

Once we have that data, we can easily compare it with the current environment to add in any environment variables that the batch file set up but which didn't already exist, and update the values of any environment variables that were changed (e.g. the `PATH`).

As a part of this process we also set a new environment variable that tells the plugin that the environment has already been set up, so that if the plugin gets reloaded it doesn't try to run the operation again.

As such, if you need to change the path to the batch file or the architecture that you want to be set up for, you need to change the preference and restart Sublime.

This could be made more robust by having it do something like store the current environment before modifying it and then watching the preferences to see if that setting is changed and act accordingly, but presumably it's not often that you would need to modify these settings.

For testing purposes, I created the following simple C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello VC World!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I also created the following `sublime-build` file, based loosely off of the `C++ Single File.sublime-build` that ships with Sublime:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "cl \"${file}\" /Fe\"${file_base_name}\"",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "shell_cmd": "cl \"${file}\" /Fe\"${file_base_name}\" && \"${file_base_name}\""
        }
    ]
}
```

If you attempt to build the sample C file without the plugin, an error is generated about not being able to find `cl` (unless you have started Sublime from a developer prompt or otherwise already set up the path). With the plugin in place, you get output similar to the following:

[image: Sample C Program being executed]

Comment: This was helpful. I've lost hours trying to make ST3 build my Qt project with VS2017, to no avail. Your script just did it in a minute.

Comment: Sublime Text 4 has two separate plugin hosts running different versions of python. The build system runs in the newer one so you'll need to add the appropriate `.python-version` file to the plugin folder for this to work. If you also have other older plugins that require these environment variables, then you'll probably need two copies of the plugin one with and without the `python-version` file in order to set the variables for both hosts.

Comment: @JoshuaWebb that is correct; the default `exec` command which is used for build systems runs in the new host, but so do plugins in your `User` package.  So in the general case you only need to do it once, but if you want to use custom build targets from other plugins, you would indeed need to have it in place twice.

Comment: I'm assuming that `vars_arch = settings.get("vc_vars_arch", "amd64")` should be `vars_arch = settings.get("vc_vars_arch", "x64")` for x64 architecture and the Sublime setting in the settings menu (`"vc_vars_arch": "x64"`) should also reflect that change if the architecture is x64 and not amd64 ?

Comment: The second argument to `settings().get()` is the value that is returned if the setting doesn't exist; so you could change that to what you want and then not set the setting at all. That said, I have no familiarity with the Microsoft toolchain for compilers, so I have no idea what the `arch` should be for any given purpose; the example here is based on originally provided information from elsewhere at the time, I think

Answer (score 4):

2. exactly as stated is not possible directly but Sublime Text has options for running other programs.

Make a batch file that goes to the directory that vcvarsall.bat wants (it looks at the directory it was run from, so it needs to be started from the proper dir) and runs vcvarsall.bat:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM vcdir is the directory where you should be
set vcdir="c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC"
REM go into that directory
push "%vcdir%"
REM Run vcvarsall.bat to set the env vars
call vcvarsall.bat amd64
REM Get back to the directory we were in initially
popd
```

If you're ok running this batch file during build (if you only need it for the build process and you don't mind rerunning it every time) then follow these instructions to [add that batch file to your build settings in sublime text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789410/how-to-edit-sublime-text-build-settings)

A more elegant approach would be to find out how to get Sublime Text 3 to run a program just once on startup (rather than at build time). I'd bet money that's possible, but I need to get back to work now...

Comment: Try adding `start /D"D:\software\SublimeText 3_x64" /b sublime_text.exe %* ` to the end of the batch file content I supplied above. It will start sublime_text.exe in an environment where vcvarsall.bat has set appropriate settings. The catch is that you then need to use that batch file to open files(rather than opening them with sublime_text.exe directly). You would need to redo your file associations to go with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here works for me

`cl` and `link` needs a lot of environment variables, for example: `INCLUDE` for include headers, `LIB_PATH` for linking

find *vcvarsall.bat*, then open `cmd`

#### step1

```
HOME>vcvarsall.bat x64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.1.0-pre.1.1
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

HOME>py
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from os import environ
>>> for key, val in environ.items(): # or ugly output: print(environ)
...   print('%s: %s, ' % (repr(key), repr(val)))
...
'APPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\林仁傑\\AppData\\Roaming',
'COMMANDPROMPTTYPE': 'Native', ... # copy here
```

copy python output

#### step2

create a new plugin, save to User package path

```py
from threading import Thread
from os import environ
from sublime import status_message

def plugin_loaded():
    vc_env = {
    # paste your cmd python output here
    }
    for key, val in vc_env.items():
        environ[key] = val
    status_message('VC environ is ready')
```

#### step3

create a build system, save to User package

```json
{
        "name": "VC++",
        "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
        "shell_cmd": "cl /EHsc /W3 \"${file}\" /Fe\"${file_base_name}\"",
        "working_dir": "${file_path}",
        "encoding": "cp950", // your locale encoding
        "variants":
        [
            {
                "name": "Run",
                "shell_cmd": "cl /EHsc /W3 \"${file}\" /Fe\"${file_base_name}\"  && start cmd /c \"${file_base_name}\""
            }
        ]
}
```

#### step4

`Tools`->`Build With`, select `VC++` or `VC++ - Run` to compile or run your C/C++ file

`[note]`: you should check your python plugin syntax is correct