# How can I persist env vars on Sublime Text?

Tags: python, environment-variables, sublimetext3

I'd like to run this script at startup on a sublime text session:

```
import os
import sys
import re
import subprocess
from pprint import pprint


def check_vs_env():
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen("cl",
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             shell=False)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
        print(stdout)
    except:
        print("Visual studio compiler not found!")

print('-' * 80)
check_vs_env()
print('-' * 80)

print("VS environment setup")
p = subprocess.Popen("vcvarsall.bat amd64 && set",
                     cwd=r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC",
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     shell=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print("Finished VS environment setup [OK]")
print('-' * 80)

print("ST environment setup")
for varname, varvalue in re.findall(r'^(.*?)=(.*)', stdout.decode("utf-8"), re.MULTILINE):
    os.environ[varname] = varvalue
print("ST environment setup [OK]")

print('-' * 80)
check_vs_env()
print('-' * 80)
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Visual studio compiler not found!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VS environment setup
Finished VS environment setup [OK]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ST environment setup
ST environment setup [OK]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23918 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

b'usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]\r\n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So far so good, but once I check the os.environ in the SublimeText3 console it seems the new content is not persisted.

Any clue how to go about this?

**ADDITIONAL NOTES**

The communication from my script to SublimeText is not done properly.

On the other hand, modifying os.environ from SublimeText console and then read it from my script works ok.

Comment: Environment variables set in a script will not persist after the script executes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/716046/3642398. You might find this plugin helpful: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Environment%20Settings

Comment: @elethan Not really, that package will help in a per-project basis, I want to run sublime text with the vs environment as exposed in this other [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881091/how-to-run-sublimetext-with-visual-studio-environment-enabled/)

Comment: What exactly is your end goal? Do you want to run build systems from within Sublime that utilize env vars set by `vcvarsall.bat`? This question and your last suffer from [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you need to define what you ultimately want to do, as there very well may be another way besides what you're trying right now.

Comment: @MattDMo You're absolutely right! My goal is quite simple actually, I'd like been able to have hundred of swig sublime-project files within the same sublime text workspace and being able to build & test those wrappers effortlessly inside sublime text without switching context (similar approach to VS). Said otherwise, I want to improve my workflow to spend more time coding and less time doing unnecesary stuff like opening terminals, setting env vars, typing commands, I just want to use mouse and shortcuts like in VS to improve my coding sessions, that's pretty much. Hope it makes sense

Comment: The question [How to run Sublime Text with visual studio environment enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881091/how-to-run-sublimetext-with-visual-studio-environment-enabled/) (also by BPL) has an answer to this question.