# Sublime Text: SublimeGDB doesn't stop at the breakpoint

Tags: debugging, gdb, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

This is a similar question to [sublimegdb can not stop in the breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962474) but nobody answers that one so I decided to open a new question.

I just installed sublimeGDB plugin in my sublime text 3 and set a breakpoint successfully by pressing F9. When I pressed F5 to run, the program didn't stop at the breakpoint --  it just finished running while the GDB view showed up for about 0.5 sec then disappeared.

Here's some output in my console view:

```
Will write debug info to file: stdout
Running: gdb --interpreter=mi ./ex8
In directory: //Users//jimmy/workspace
Process: <subprocess.Popen object at 0x1037a1110>
pty: 41, tty: None, name: /var/folders/m2/7h27qgr17v1bqyphh7wq6tpw0000gn/T/tmpnvs3afgdb_stdout: broken pipe
GDB session ended
gdb_stderr: /bin/sh: gdb: command not found
gdb_stderr: broken pipe
```

Comment: Obvious question: do you have gdb installed on your system?

Answer (score 1):

> `gdb_stderr: /bin/sh: gdb: command not found`

This says: sublime ran `/bin/sh`, and asked it to run `gdb`, but no program called `gdb` was found on the `PATH`.

It *must* be that either:

- you don't have GDB installed on your system *at all*, or
- it is installed somewhere, but it's not on whatever `PATH` the sublime invokes `/bin/sh` with.